# Using quoted symbols in a graph structure

Tags: scheme

I'm building a graph structure in Scheme. The graph is bidirectional and more importantly, there is no set order in which the nodes are created. I create nodes with the following code:

```
(define (make-node data parents children)
    `((data . ,data) 
      (parents . ,parents)
      (children . ,children)))
```

As you can see, I use an association list for nodes. My getters seem to work fine, here's the getter for `data` as an example:

```
(define (node-data node)
    (let ((data (assq 'data node)))
        (cond
            ((null? data) #f)
            (else (cdr data)))))
```

However, I'm unable to traverse the graph and use neighboring nodes. Here's an example how I create nodes:

```
(define (node-a (make-node "a" '() '('node-b)))
```

To access `node-b` from `node-a`, I do

```
(car (node-children node-a))
```

but it returns `(quote node-b)` instead of `node-b`.

My question is, can I unquote at this point? How to do that?

For what it is worth, I've written the same algorithm in other languages. I've had to use a separate mapping container for all nodes. I could do that in Scheme, too, but since Scheme supports quoting, I hope I could make it prettier in Scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your representation of nodes seems coherent, however you can find easier representations. `((DATA) (PARENTS) (CHILDREN))` is more direct as constructor and as getters `data=CAR`, `children = CADDR`, `parent = CADR`, is enough.

Your mistake is that you use `'('node-b)` instead of `'(node-b)`.  Also,

```
(cond
 ((null? data) #f)
 (else (cdr data))))
```

can be written as `(and data (cdr data))`

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. I changed the code to use `'(node-b)`, which, to my surprise, works and now I correctly get `node-b` when asking for the first child of `node-a`. However, it seems I get the symbol, not the variable, as I was expecting. I must have some gross misunderstanding of quoting in Scheme. Most importantly, if I do `(node-data node-b)` I get what I'm looking for, but `(node-data (car (node-children node-a)))` fails. I guess it's not possible to do what I was looking for here, i.e. using quoted symbols as references in a graph structure?

Comment: @keelefi Oh, if you want the value you do `\`(,node-b)`instead

Comment: I don't think that can possibly work because `node-b` has not been defined when `node-a` is being constructed. In fact, I get `Unbound variable: node-b`.

Comment: @keelefi oh, sorry.  If the graph has loops, you need to implement some lazy-evaluation mechanism.  For example, instead of defining a node with `(define node-x ...)` you need to define a procedure that defines a node and that procedure will walk inside the values of the nodes that were previously defined.  There are many ways to implement lazy-evaluation, if you do not manage to do it, ask about how you tried and did not work.

Comment: @keelefi  to implement loops you need to keep an association list with `( (node-x . value-node-x) ... )`.  When you define a new node you need to update this list.  There are many ways to update it.  A way is to replace node-x in all already-defined nodes in the moment when you define node-x, other way is to keep the list as symbols and when you need the value of the symbol `node-x` to loop inside this environment of node's values.